# Why is this constexpr function ill-formed?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

According to 10.1.5 [dcl.constexpr] paragraph 5 ([N4659](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf)),

> For a constexpr function or constexpr constructor that is neither defaulted nor a template, **if no argument values exist** such that an invocation of the function or constructor could be an evaluated subexpression of a core constant expression (8.20), or, for a constructor, a constant initializer for some object (6.6.2), the
>   program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required. [ Example:
>
> ```
> constexpr int f(bool b)
>     { return b ? throw 0 : 0; }         // OK
> constexpr int f() { return f(true); }   // ill-formed, no diagnostic required
>
> ...
> ```
>
> —end example ]

I'm not sure why the above program is ill-formed. I can certainly see that `f(true)` is not a part of a core constant expression. **However, the argument value `false` exists such that `f(false)` is a part of a core constant expression.** What's the problem?

Comment: `throw` is runtime only.  The first definition is okay, because you do not attempt to invoke runtime stuff at compile time.  In the second case you do and therefore usually get a compiler error (even though no diagnostic is required).

Comment: No call to `f()` is a `constexpr`

Comment: @PasserBy Do you mean to say that `f(false)` is not a subexpression of a core constant expression?

Comment: `f(bool)` is well-formed, `f(false)` is a core constant expression. It's `f()` that can never be a core constant expression. All argument values (in this case, the empty set) results in a `throw`

Comment: @PasserBy Oh. You're right. Thanks a million.

Comment: Are your referencing the C++14 standard by any chance? I don't see the text you quoted in C++11. See https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.constexpr#5.

Comment: @RSahu I'm **truly** sorry for the inconvenience. I should have mentioned the draft. It's [N4659](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf).

Comment: Thank you all. You guys are the best.

Comment: @PasserBy You should move that into the answer box down there v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f(bool)` is well formed, `f(false)` is a core constant expression.

Its `f()` that is ill-formed, all argument values, in this case the empty set, results in calling `f(true)` which in turn throws.