# Why could a non-constexpr function call std::format in Clang

Tags: c++, format, clang, c++20, constexpr

As far as I know, a `constexpr` function can not call a non-`constexpr` function. But, it looks like in clang, a `constexpr` function can call `std::format()` (which I know does not have the `constexpr` specifier).
What's the reason? Why does clang handle them differently?

```cpp
// It is compiled without any error
constexpr std::string print() {
    return std::format("hello");
}

std::string myformat() {
    return "hello";
}

// compiler error: non-constexpr function 'myformat' cannot be used in a constant expression
constexpr std::string myprint() {
    return myformat();
}
```

Both of them are ill-formed in MSVC, reporting [error C3615](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c3615?view=msvc-170).

Comment: What is C3615? Why do you want us to search it?

Comment: at a guess whichever standard library you are using does have a `constexpr` `std::format`

Comment: If there is no way to call a constexpr function and actually have it be constexpr then your code is ill formed; no diagnostics required.  Looking for a dupe target.

Comment: Which clang version accepts the code?

Comment: I'm on the fence with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45025808/why-is-this-constexpr-function-ill-formed).  looking for better

Comment: @NathanOliver Not in C++23: https://wg21.link/P2448R2 (Not that clang has implemented this yet)

Comment: @Artyer The Q is tagged C++20.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `std::format` and `myformat` is that `std::format` takes a parameter of type `std::format_string<>`, which has a `consteval` constructor. Apparently this `consteval` constructor stops Clang from producing a warning.

And it also happens with `constexpr` constructors.

```cpp
struct A {
    constexpr // clang warns if this line were commented out
    A(int) {}
};

int f(A);

constexpr int g() { return f(1); }
```

It's unclear to me why Clang fails to produce a warning in this case. I guess it's a bug somewhere in Clang.